# How do I treat multiple particle emitters and multiple curve guides?

Tags: force-fields

[image]
[image]

I often work on projects where fluid or gas is flowing through a pipe. I would like to use bubbles to show fluid in motion. Sometimes these pipes/tubes are very close to each other. Can you please tell me why this simple assembly is buggy? The last tube hates the force fields.

The assembly consists of 4 curves with (curve force fields) and 4 particle emitters. The 4th curve doesn't seem to guide the particles at all. I thought that the max and min strength of the curve guide would determine whether that curve was influential to the motion.

And if anyone has an ingenious way of rendering flow through pipes/conduit. I would love to hear your method.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YuQuAQ9f1YlMJHkIOSqBjExdvbsO4eA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Wow this is very cool! But why don't you try it with geometry nodes? It would be a very easy setup and would work 100%.

Comment: Good idea. Show me how! It would make my assembly cleaner, with better housekeeping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All curve guides are influencing all particles with no further settings. Yes, you can try with min and max, but that's very difficult. In a simple case like yours where you only want to have influence one particle system to one curve (i hope you only want that) i would work with effector collections. You can easily assign a collection to a particle system, so that only forces in that collection will influence your particles.

so just move each of your curve guides to a different collection and assign that in your particle system.

[image]

[image]

Note: the curve direction is important. You mixed up one curve direction in your blend file.

Comment: Thanks for getting it to work! One member mentioned using geo nodes for this, which sounds like a better approach.

Comment: for sure you could do this with geometry nodes, but since this question was about particles, i answered with particles. But it would be a pretty complex geometry nodes tree, because you use different things of particles here: curve guide, different sizes, maybe even different speeds and so on. All these things have to be manually rebuild in GN. Maybe you wanna open a new question for this?

Comment: If it's a complex node tree, then let's keep it simple like this particle setup. Thanks!